# Remove smoothbars in a particular slide

Tags: beamer, presentations

I want to remove smoothbars from the outline slide and the last slide. How am I supposed to do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} }

\AtBeginSection[] {
    \ifnum\insertsubsectionstartpage=\insertsectionstartpage
    \relax%
    \else%
    \begingroup
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-0.9\baselineskip}}{}
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline} %
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]  
    \end{frame}
    \endgroup
\fi%
}

\AtBeginSubsection[] % Do nothing for \subsection*
{
    \begingroup
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-0.9\baselineskip}}{}
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
\endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother


\title[short title]{Insert your title}
\author{Author}
\institute[]{Author's University}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------
\section{First Section}
%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Subsection Example}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Paragraphs of Text}
Sed \alert{highlighted text} iaculis dapibus gravida. Morbi sed tortor erat, nec interdum arcu. Sed id lorem lectus. Quisque viverra augue id sem ornare non aliquam nibh tristique. Aenean in ligula nisl. Nulla sed tellus ipsum. Donec vestibulum ligula non lorem vulputate fermentum accumsan neque mollis.\\~\\

Sed diam enim, sagittis nec condimentum sit amet, ullamcorper sit amet libero. Aliquam vel dui orci, a porta odio. Nullam id suscipit ipsum. Aenean lobortis commodo sem, ut commodo leo gravida vitae. Pellentesque vehicula ante iaculis arcu pretium rutrum eget sit amet purus. Integer ornare nulla quis neque ultrices lobortis. Vestibulum ultrices tincidunt libero, quis commodo erat ullamcorper id.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\Huge{\centerline{The End}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
`?

Comment: or `{ \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}` if you just want to remove the headline

Comment: Yeah, I was doing the same thing earlier, but I missed the extra {} after headline, and I couldn't find the error in my code. After correcting, I implemented the same but there were white spaces on the header. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be to use a `[plain]` frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```